# Using button variable in other button of form

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a simple project for my school and I need to use 2 buttons one of them needs information from another. I didn't find anything that could help so this is my last resource

```
'this button takes information'
Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim c1 As String
    c1 = InputBox("Introduza o Primeiro Numero:", "Entrada de Dados")
    Dim c2 As String
    c2 = InputBox("Introduza o Segundo Numero:", "Entrada de Dados")

End Sub
'this one needs it to show the user'
    Public Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        MsgBox("Os números são"  "e" )
    End Sub
```

All I need is a way to use the information of the field the user completes i tried ti use the variable buts it gives me an error.

Comment: Not sure to have understood correctly, but if you need to use the variables c1 and c2 inside the Button3_Click code then you need to understand the concept of [Variable Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/how-to-control-the-scope-of-a-variable)

Comment: That's it thank u so much. I just wasn't searching well.Its the first time I work with it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you came to the conclusion that you need to move those variable declarations out to class level:

```
Private c1 As String    
Private c2 As String

Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    c1 = InputBox("Introduza o Primeiro Numero:", "Entrada de Dados")
    c2 = InputBox("Introduza o Segundo Numero:", "Entrada de Dados")   
End Sub

Public Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    MessageBox.Show("c1 = " & c1 & ", c2 = " & c2)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks i explored the steves response and got there by myself. thanks for helping me anyway. I'm just a student trying to learn new languages